# Adding element from one array object to another arraobject in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two array's say

```
let array1 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4"}];

let array2 = [{"name": "a", "id" : "1", "temp" : "temp1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2", "temp" : "temp2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3", "temp" : "temp3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4", "temp" : "temp4"}];
```

ow my requirement is
From my array2 I need to get the "name" element and search if that "name" value exist in array1, then I add the "temp" entry into my array1 ( without using a different array) and leaving all the other elements as it is.
In short my final array1 should be like this

```
[{"name": "a", "id" : "1", "temp" : "temp1"}, {"name": "b", "id" : "2", "temp" : "temp2"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "3", "temp" : "temp3"}, {"name": "c", "id" : "4", "temp" : "temp4"}]
```

I can try the for loop but I need a more efficient way to acheive the same .

I tried this code

```
array2.forEach(function(e){
    if(array1.map(f => f.id).indexOf(e["id"]) != -1) {
        array1[array1.indexOf(e["id"])].name= e["name"];
    }
})
```

Comment: Include your for-loop attempt and we can go from there.

Comment: A for loop is likely to be the most efficient (if you mean pure speed). What have you tried so far? Please may you add a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can achieve this using the Array.prototype.map() method:

```js
array1 = array1.map(item1 => {
  const item2 = array2.find(item => item.name === item1.name);
  if (item2) {
    return {
      ...item1,
      temp: item2.temp
    }
  }
  return item1;
});
```

This will iterate over each element in array1, and for each element it will find the corresponding element in array2 using the Array.prototype.find() method. If it finds a matching element, it will return a new object that includes all the properties from item1 and the temp property from item2. If it does not find a matching element, it will return the original item1 object.

This approach has a time complexity of O(n), which is more efficient than using a nested loop.

Comment: Using map is likely to be slower than a for loop.

Comment: Thanks @AllenJoy and evolutionBox. I got the solution based on your code and suggestion. Thanks a lot.My Final code is        'array1.forEach(item1 => {
  const item2 = array2.find(item => item.name === item1.name);
  if (item2) {
    
      item1.temp =  item2.temp
      
    
  }
  
});'

Comment: This does _not_ have the "time complexity" (I assume you meant the "upper bound" of the procedure) of `O(n)`, and the upper bound complexity will _match_ that of a nested for loop (_not_ the one in the question), because both `map` using `find` for every item in `array1` and a nested loop will do exactly the same thing. The upper bound of the procedure is rather `O(n*m)` where `n` is size of `array1` and `m` is size of `array2`.